# Can'nt I create channels in Microsoft live streaming using the API

Tags: c#, json, azure, api, live-streaming

How to create a channel by api?

Use the postman to test the api:

```
//header


 POST api/Channels HTTP/1.1:
    DataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx  
    MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx  
    Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata  
    Accept-Charset: UTF-8  
    x-ms-version: 2.11  
    Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata  
    Host: https://<mydomin>.restv2.northeurope.media.azure.net/api/  
    User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services  
    Authorization: Bearer "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ii1zeE1KTUxDSURXTVRQdlp5SjZ0eC1DRHh3MCIsImtpZCI6Ii1zeE1KTUxDS"

//body


  {  
    "Id":5,  
    "Name":"testchannel001",  
    "Description":"",  
    "Created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",  
    "LastModified":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",  
    "State":Stopping,  
    "Input":  
       {  
       "KeyFrameInterval":null,  
       "StreamingProtocol":"FragmentedMP4",  
       "AccessControl":  
          {  
             "IP":  
             {  
                "Allow":[{"Name":"testName1","Address":"<myip>","SubnetPrefixLength":24}]  
             }  
          },  
       "Endpoints":[]  
       },  
    "Preview":  
       {  
       "AccessControl":  
          {  
             "IP":  
             {  
                "Allow":[{"Name":"testName2","Address":"<myip>","SubnetPrefixLength":24}]  
             }  
          },  
          "Endpoints":[]  
       },  
    "Output":  
       {  
       "Hls":  
          {  
             "FragmentsPerSegment":1  
          }  
       },  
    "CrossSiteAccessPolicies":  
       {  
          "ClientAccessPolicy":null,  
          "CrossDomainPolicy":null  
       }  
    }
```

Could not get any response, and there was an error connecting to https://.restv2.northeurope.media.azure.net/api/Channels.

Is this a coding or network error?

Comment: I hope that value in the `Authentication` header is not a valid token. You have not described what problem you encounter. And you cannot expect others to run the request with their own authentication token. Please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: Thank you and the authentication code is not valid, the first time I deal with api my problem is how to create a channel via api and i can not find online explanations on this topic, i tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/channel#create_channels    Do I have to enter all the existing value